# elements dissapear when i add more selectors to .empty

Tags: jquery

alright so when i add another .empty or add another selector to my .empty i lose my text element. if i dont have the second selector both my text and image appear normal. not sure what is causing this, also any other tips would be appreciated.

```js
    $("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
    let select = $('#dropdown').val();
    $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/' + select + '.json?api-key=284e1a4e58644ff8b53eb355b79961', 
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    $('.stories-1, .text-1').empty();
    $('.text-1').append(data.results[0].abstract);
    $('.stories-1').append('<img src=' + data.results[0].multimedia[0].url + '>');

    })
    })

    .fail(function(err) {
    throw err;
    })
    $('.stories-1').on('click', function() {
    window.open('<a href=' + data.results[0].url + '>');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>sections ...</a></option>
    <option value="home">Home</option>
    <option value="arts">Arts</option>
    <option value="business">Business</option>
    <option value="sports">sports</option>
    <option value="technology">Technology</option>
    <option value="fashion">fashion</a></option>
    </select>
<div class="news">
        <section class="stories-1">
            <p class="text-1"></p>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.stories-1` elements includes `.text-1` element, so `.text-1` element is removed by the following code.

```
$('.stories-1, .text-1').empty();
```

I don't understand your requirement completely, but I suggest to create a element in order to put images within `stories-1`.
The following code is creating `.img-1` to do that. Also I have fixed `window.open` part and others. Please try this code.

js:

```
$("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
  let select = $('#dropdown').val();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/' + select + '.json?api-key=284e1a4e58644ff8b53eb355b79961', 
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.img-1, .text-1').empty();
    $('.text-1').append(data.results[0].abstract);
    $('.img-1').append('<img src=' + data.results[0].multimedia[0].url + '>');
    $('.stories-1').on('click', function() {
      window.open(data.results[0].url);
    });
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    throw err;
  })
});
```

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>sections ...</a></option>
    <option value="home">Home</option>
    <option value="arts">Arts</option>
    <option value="business">Business</option>
    <option value="sports">sports</option>
    <option value="technology">Technology</option>
    <option value="fashion">fashion</a></option>
    </select>
<div class="news">
    <section class="stories-1">
        <p class="text-1"></p>
        <p class="img-1"></p>
    </section>
```